# How do I use two scripts in one Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use two separate scripts in one sheet and only one is working.

1st script creates a custom menu with sidebar and form to enter data and upload to a sheet. 2nd script is sidebar to generate file upload form and upload files to my google drive.

I can't get both of them to work, and also I'm not a developer or know much about coding.
Just looking to get this to work and make it easy on myself to enter data and upload files as i would like to keep all this in one file and not to have multiple windows open. Trying to get both to work to keep everything in one window

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you would post your code to see how the 2 functions are interelated.

Comment: How are you trying to do it? Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have an example, as I am not sure what exactly is meant by "one sheet".  If you mean two scripts in one file, here is a sample of how I would set it up.

```
function twoAppsScripts() {
script1();
script2();
}

function script1() {
do something...
}

function script2() {
do something
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify and share a sample of what you are trying to achieve.